# contentView not changing dynamicly programmed content. Worked this morning and I did not even touched it

Tags: java, android

Today morning I had some problems with eclipse and its common bug with R not regenerating.
After I solved it I wrote a lots of new packages so reverting to last working commit is not an option and it is 17:00 here where I am so...

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mActivity = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.android_messenger_conversation, null);
    setContentView(contentView);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        Log.i("ConversationActivity/onStart","extras is not null");
        String extra = extras.getString(MainActivity.CONVERSATION_EXTRA);
        Log.i("ConversationActivity/onStart","got extra gave value: "+extra);
        if(extra!=withWhoWeAreChatting){
            withWhoWeAreChatting = extra;
        }
        ArrayList<ConversationInfo> arrayList = Conversation.getConversationWith(getApplicationContext(), extra);

        contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.android_messenger_conversation, null);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.android_messgener_conversation_LinearLayout);
        for(int i = arrayList.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
            Log.i("ConversationActivity/onStart","Doing for loop: "+i);
            ConversationInfo conversationInfo = arrayList.get(i);
            if(conversationInfo.getProtocol()!=null){
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.android_messenger_inbox_message, null);
                TextView inbox_message = (TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.inbox_message);
                inbox_message.setText(conversationInfo.getBody());

                linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
            }
            else{
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.android_messenger_sent_message, null);
                TextView inbox_message = (TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.sentMessage);
                inbox_message.setText(conversationInfo.getBody());

                linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
            }
        }
        setContentView(contentView);
    }
}
```

setContentView(contentView)  at the end here just above my comment is not changing anything. By logs I checked everything inside the loop is executed without errors.

Any ideas?

I could send you some polish beer by mail if you live in Europe :)

Cheers

Comment: Why do you do "setContentView(contentView)" twice? If you save it in a global variable in onCreate (like you are doing) I think you can modify its values without having to inflate and set it again.

Comment: May be the solution. Trying it right now

Comment: Nope. That is not the problem.

Comment: I guess you tried to clean & rebuild the project, right? I can't see what's wrong with your code. Can you test if adding a new TextView to linearLayout instead of adding relativeLayout displays something? Something like: **** TextView tv = new TextView(this); tv.setText(conversationInfo.getBody()); linearLayout.addView(tv); ****  Place this code inside if and inside else.

Comment: In such a case I would create a member variable for debugging, store the last in the loop created `RelativeLayout` in it and create an option menu entry which logs the position of the layout (using `getTop()`, `getLeft()`, ...) and check if its parent is the linearLayout

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for trouble for everyone :)

As I mentioned I did not change anything here from the morning. But I changed my xml file for scrollview.

from this:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/android_messgener_conversation_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

to this:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/android_messgener_conversation_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

reverting this fixed my issue :) Now it works almost like a charm :)

Again sorry for trouble!

And cheers to user user1455909 - clean and rebuild is my basic when I get any kind of bug :D